# Is there a way to list broken internal hyperlinks with VBA in MS Word? (Hyperlink Subaddress)

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

In MS Word, you can create hyperlinks to a "Place in this document" so that a link takes you someplace else in the same Word file. However, if you change headers or move things around these links will sometimes break. I want to write some VBA to check for broken links.

With VBA, you can list each hyperlink subaddress using the code below:

```
Sub CheckLinks()
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count
        Debug.Print doc.Hyperlinks(i).SubAddress
    Next
End Sub
```

The output from the code above also matches what is shown in the field codes for the hyperlink.

However, I'm not really clear on how to verify if the SubAddress is correct. For example, an excerpt from the program output shows this:

```
_Find_a_Staff_1
_Edit_Organization_Settings_2
_Set_the_Staff
_Find_a_Staff_1
```

But there's no obvious way to tell what the "correct" suffix should be for a given heading. Any thoughts on how to check if these are valid?

Is there a way to get the list of all valid subaddresses for the headings in the document?

Comment: Ah, it appears that I had to set the Bookmarks.ShowHidden to true so that the hidden, automatically-created bookmarks can be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will list the hyperlinks where the corresponding bookmark does not exist in the document. (Note that it only detects missing links, not links that go to the wrong place.)

```
Sub CheckLinks()
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Dim i, j
    Dim found As Boolean

    For i = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count
       found = False
       For j = 1 To doc.Bookmarks.Count
         If doc.Range.Bookmarks(j).Name = doc.Hyperlinks(i).SubAddress Then
            found = True
         End If
       Next
       If found = False Then
          Debug.Print doc.Hyperlinks(i).SubAddress
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Taraz's macro optimized to run a bit faster by building arrays first. See comments. Also only finds internal links, Taraz's code also finds links to bookmarks in external pages

To use add it as a macro, and then you can see the output in VBA using the Immediate window from the View drop menu

```
Sub checkBookmarkNames()
'
' checkBookmarkNames Macro
'
' prints number of bookmarks, number of hyperlinks
' and a list of the hyperlinks with sub addresses not linking to bookmarks
' This speeds up the search using arrays.
' Also removes null strings,
' ones that begin _Toc and numeric strings
' Note - this only checks for exact matches
' if the bookmark differs in capitalization from
' the hyperlink it may still work
' hardcoded for a maximum of a million bookmarks or hyperlinks
' - change the 1000000 figure on remote chance you need more than that
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Dim i, j, k
Dim imax, jmax
Dim bookmarkNames(1000000) As Variant
Dim subAddress(1000000) As Variant
' find the bookmarks
Debug.Print "bookmarks:"
k = 1
For j = 1 To doc.Bookmarks.Count
 ' skip any that start _Toc (table of contents) or any numeric bookmarks
 If doc.Bookmarks(j).Name = vbNullString Or IsNumeric(doc.Bookmarks(j).Name) Then
 Else
  If InStr(1, doc.Bookmarks(j).Name, "_Toc") = 1 Then
  Else
   bookmarkNames(k) = doc.Bookmarks(j).Name
   k = k + 1
  End If
' Debug.Print bookmarkNames(j)
 End If
Next
' print the number of bookmarks
jmax = k
Debug.Print jmax

' find the hyperlinks
Debug.Print "hyperlinks:"
k = 1
For j = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count
 ' skip any that start _Toc (table of contents) or any numeric hyperlink subaddresses
 If doc.Hyperlinks(j).subAddress = vbNullString Or IsNumeric(doc.Hyperlinks(j).subAddress) Then
 Else
  If InStr(1, doc.Hyperlinks(j).subAddress, "_Toc") = 1 Then
  Else
   ' ignore all external hyperlinks
   If doc.Hyperlinks(j).Address = vbNullString Then
    subAddress(k) = doc.Hyperlinks(j).subAddress
    k = k + 1
   End If
  End If
' Debug.Print doc.Hyperlinks(j).subAddress
 End If
Next
' print the number of hyperlinks
imax = k
Debug.Print imax
Debug.Print "Searching for broken links"
Dim nfound
nfound = 0
' Loop through the hyperlinks and with each one loop through to see if they link to valid bookmakrs
Dim found As Boolean
For i = 1 To imax
 found = False
 For j = 1 To jmax
  If bookmarkNames(j) = subAddress(i) Then
   found = True
  End If
 Next
 If found = False Then
  nfound = nfound + 1
  Debug.Print "Not -found: " + subAddress(i)
 End If
Next
Debug.Print "Number of broken links found"
Debug.Print nfound
End Sub
```